# Do all Dell r520s allow for 8 drives?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I noticed there are some models that only have 4 bays available and have the other 4 protected by plastic...

[Picture of Dell r520](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI27Y.jpg)

Can you still transform these into 8 bay servers? Why do some of the r520s have the remaining 4 blocked, while others do not?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [owner's manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/nz/en/nzbsd1/poweredge-r520/r520systemsownersmanual-v2/front-panel-features-and-indicators?guid=guid-fde0e997-29e2-4c46-985d-fba210f0ec1e&lang=en-us), the 4-bay systems are software RAID and the 8-bay systems are hardware RAID.

It also says:

> NOTE: Dual slot hard-drive blanks are available only on software RAID systems. The blank hard-drive slots are not available for software RAID.

So if you have a 4-bay system you cannot use all eight slots unless you first [upgrade the system to hardware RAID](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/Poweredge-R520-RAID-Controller-Upgrade-Question-s/td-p/4113372).